# ¿En qué países de habla hispana alrededor del mundo la palabra "lonche" significa "una comida que se come al mediodía"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, dialectos

Un señor me dijo una vez que, en su país, la palabra "lonche" tiene el mismo significado que la palabra "bocadillo", o "torta", o "sandwhich".

En otras palabras, un "lonche" es un poco de carne, verduras y/o salsa que se coloca entr dos rebanadas de pan.

Sin embargo, una mujer de otro lugar me dijo que "lonche" es una comida que se come entre las 10:00 de la mañana y las 2:00 de la tarde.

¿En qué países de habla hispana alrededor del mundo la palabra "lonche" significa una comida que se come al mediodía, pero no significa pan ocualquier alimento en particular. solo una hora del dia ?

Comment: inicie la respueats tipo wiki comunitario, pues cada pais tendra sua *usos y costumbres* alrededor del *lonçhe* y asi queda todo en una sola respuesta

Answer (score 1):

### México

- En todo el país, *Lonche* se entiende como el alimento que describes, similar al sándwich.
- Sólo en el norte es sinónimo con el horario de consumir algún refrigerio durante el medio día. Esto da piena holarqntess pero correctas oraciones como *Comeré un Lonche en el lonche de hoy*

Answer (score 1):

- Según la RAE, en Ecuador, Guatemala, México, Nicaragua y Panamá, es una «comida ligera del mediodía». En España, jamás lo he escuchado.
- «Lonche» es un anglicismo que deriva de *lunch*, por lo que en origen debería tener el significado de almuerzo, refrigerio o aperitivo, y no de un tipo presentación de un alimento.
- Que en ciertos lugares haya derivado a significar algo como *sandwhich*, quizás sea por la similitud de este anglicismo con «loncha», que indica porción ancha y delgada de un alimento (por ejemplo «lonchas de carne»), pero esto es solo una suposición mía, basada en que es una palabra similar de uso muy común en español (al menos en España).

Answer (score 0):

> #### **lonche.** <sub>(Del ingl. *lunch*).</sub>
>
> 1. 1. m. *EU, Mx, Gu, Ni, Pa, Ec, Ch:N; PR,* p.u. Comida ligera del mediodía. ([lonch](https://www.asale.org/damer/lonch); [lunch](https://www.asale.org/damer/lunch)).
>    2. *Pa, Pe, Ch:N.* Refrigerio ligero que se toma por la tarde.
>    3. *Bo:SO.* Comida que lleva el minero como almuerzo o cena.

- [Diccionario de americanismos](https://www.asale.org/damer/lonche)